# How to Read and Write to Amazon ElasticCache using ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, amazon-web-services, amazon-elasticache

I am interested to know what commands allows me to write and read data to and from Amazon ElasticCache using the ASP.NET SDK. I've viewed the online documentation but couldn't figure out how it is done.

What I did in the code: I created  to keys in the web.config to store the Id and Access password.

```
AmazonElastiCacheClient client = new AmazonElastiCacheClient(ElasticCache_Id, ElasticCache_Pass);
```

Initialize the AmazonElasticCacheClient object and pass the credentials strings.

I need a sample code that will demonstrate how to put data and how to retrieve data from the ElasticCache cluster. thanks.

Comment: Can you share the idea if you have gotten some solution?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you can only manage elasticcache clusters through the AWS SDK.

You can use any memcached client to read and write to elasticcache since that is the underlying technology.

Here is an example:
http://geekswithblogs.net/shaunxu/archive/2010/04/07/first-round-playing-with-memcached.aspx